# Working with loops in C++

Tags: c++

Guys am working on a loop that accepts integers but I want the loop to break once I enter any non integer.I don't want the program to terminate, I just want the loop to break. How can I do that in C++?

Comment: Could you Please put here code?

Comment: Why did you tag this with "d"?

Comment: And the answer is that you need to use the `break` statement.  Find a C++ tutorial / text book and read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) in an if statement to check the type of the input and [break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w.aspx) if `TryParse` returns false